# Why an extra SQL query is needed after a successful update when version number controlled by db in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, version-control, optimistic-locking

I was reading [this article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/) and I couldn't understand why when we delegate the versioning data control to the database in Hibernate, after a successful update, another SQL query is needed to retrieve the version number back from the database.

Here comes the example. We have an entity called Product.

This is the mapping configuration:

```
<hibernate-mapping package=”example”>
<class name=”Product”>
<id name=”id”>
  <generator class=”native” />
</id>
<version name=”version” type=”long” generated=”always”/>
<property name=”name” not-null=”true” />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

These are the queries generated after updating a product:

```
Hibernate:
/* update example.Product */ 
update Product
set
 name=?
where
 id=?
 and version=?

Hibernate:
/* get generated state example.Product */ 
select product_.version as version8_
from
 Product product_
where
 product_.id=?
```

I know why version control is needed, but what I don't understand is **why the version number is retrieved after we update the product** ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra query is necessary, because hibernate needs to know new version value. Otherwise the cached hibernate entity needs to be invalidated.
When hibernate handles the version by itself, the new value is known so no need for extra query to the database.